# Call a controller action on a button click without javascript in yii2

Tags: yii2

I've 3 fields and a button in `index2.php` file. These are not from any model. I need to pass the fields as parameter and call controller action stockbetweendates. I don't want to use `javascript` or `ajax` for certain reason. How can I do it by only `yii2` code?

index2.php

```
<div class="sellitem-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
                <label for="upc" class="control-label"><p class="text-info">Product Code&nbsp;<i class="icon-star"></i></p></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="upc" class="span3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
                <label for="upc" class="control-label"><p class="text-info">Start Date&nbsp;<i class="icon-star"></i></p></label>
                <?= DatePicker::widget([
                //'label' => 'Startdate',
                'name' => 'startdate',
                'id' => 'startdate',
                //'value' => '02-16-2012',
                'template' => '{addon}{input}',
                    'clientOptions' => [
                        'autoclose' => true,
                        'todayHighlight' => true,
                        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
                    ]
                ]);?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
                <label for="upc" class="control-label"><p class="text-info">End Date&nbsp;<i class="icon-star"></i></p></label>
                <?= DatePicker::widget([
                //'label' => 'Startdate',
                'name' => 'enddate',
                'id' => 'enddate',
                //'value' => '02-16-2012',
                'template' => '{addon}{input}',
                    'clientOptions' => [
                        'autoclose' => true,
                        'todayHighlight' => true,
                        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
                    ]
                ]);?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
                <label for="desc" class="control-label"><p class="text-info">Product Desc&nbsp;<i class="icon-star"></i></p></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="desc" class="span3">
            </div>

    </div>
    <p>
        <div class="form-group pull-right">
            <button id="yourButton" class="btn btn-primary" >Seach</button>           
        </div>
    </p>
</div>
```

Controller Action

```
public function actionStockbetweendates($productname, $startdate, $enddate) {

        $modelProduction = Puritem::find()->where(['pi_upc' => $productname]);
        $searchModel1  = new PuritemsbSearch();
        $dataProvider1 = $searchModel1->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $productname);

        $modelSell  = Sellitem::find()->where(['si_iupc' => $productname]);
        $searchModel2 = new SellitemsbSearch();       
        $dataProvider2 = $searchModel2->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $productname);

        $content = $this->renderPartial('_printproductledgerbtdt', [
            'modelProduction' => $modelProduction,
            'dataProvider1' => $dataProvider1,
            'searchModel1'  => $searchModel1,
            //'data'=> $data,

            'modelSell' => $modelSell,
            'searchModel2' => $searchModel2,          
            'dataProvider2' => $dataProvider2,

            'productname' => $productname,
            //'prodesc' => $prodesc,

            ]);
        $footer = "<table name='footer' width=\"1000\">
           <tr>             
             <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"right\">Signature</td>
           </tr>
         </table>";
        $pdf = new Pdf([
            'mode'=> Pdf::MODE_UTF8,
            'format'=> Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
            'destination'=> Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
            'orientation'=> Pdf::ORIENT_LANDSCAPE,
            //'destination' => Pdf::DEST_DOWNLOAD,
            'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
            // any css to be embedded if required
            'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}', 
             // set mPDF properties on the fly
            'options' => ['title' => 'Print Party Ledger'],
            //'options' => ['defaultfooterline' => 0,],
            'options' => ['defaultheaderline' => 0,],
             // call mPDF methods on the fly
            'methods' => [
                'SetHeader'=>['Ledger'], 
                //'SetFooter'=>[$footer],
            ],
            'content' => $content,

        ]);
        return $pdf->render();

    }
```

**Update**
I'm trying to call the controller action from a form and tried the below -

```
<div class="sellitem-form">

    <?php $form = Html::beginForm([
        'id' => 'form-id',
        'method' => 'get',
        'action' => ['/stock/sellitem/printproductledger2']
    ]); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group"> 
            <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2">
                <?= Html::input('text', 'productname', $productname->productname, ['class' => $productname]) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php Html::endForm(); ?>

</div>
```

I'm getting `Undefined offset: 0` error.

Comment: you can use form to submit data

Comment: That's fine. But how can I get the data from the textboxes and pass as parameter to the controller? In the controller action I need to pass the parameters.

Comment: if the 3 field are from you model .. you could use a simple Yii2 url::to with param  ...

Comment: They are not from any model. Sorry, I didn't mention it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GET mthod , so , you can get parameter value from URL in your controller.

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'form-id',
    'method' => 'get',
]);
echo $form->field($Model, 'field1');
echo $form->field($Model, 'field2');
echo $form->field($Model, 'field3');
echo Html::submitButton('Find', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']);
ActiveForm::end();
```

Comment: Hi Amitesh, Sorry I didn't inform earlier... The fields are not coming from any model. I'm getting error - Undefined variable model.

Comment: you have to define a model for that , and in that model you have to add fields either public variable or database field.